# In Gtk, when using Drag and Drop in a TreeView, how do I keep from dropping between rows?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, gtk, gtk#, gtktreeview

I'm testing a window that looks something like this:

[image]

Dragging a Tag to a Card links the Tag to the Card. So does dragging a Card to a Tag.

It's meaningless to drop a tag between two cards, or a card between two tags. I can ignore these outcomes in the `Handle...DataReceived` function like this:

```
if (dropPos != TreeViewDropPosition.IntoOrAfter &&
    dropPos != TreeViewDropPosition.IntoOrBefore)
    return;
```

However, when dragging, the user still sees the option to insert:

[image]

How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to connect to the `drag-motion` signal and change the default behaviour so it never indicates a before/after drop:

```
def _drag_motion(self, widget, context, x, y, etime):
    drag_info = widget.get_dest_row_at_pos(x, y)
    if not drag_info:
        return False
    path, pos = drag_info
    if pos == gtk.TREE_VIEW_DROP_BEFORE:
        widget.set_drag_dest_row(path, gtk.TREE_VIEW_DROP_INTO_OR_BEFORE)
    elif pos == gtk.TREE_VIEW_DROP_AFTER:
        widget.set_drag_dest_row(path, gtk.TREE_VIEW_DROP_INTO_OR_AFTER)
    context.drag_status(context.suggested_action, etime)
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks--I've ported most of this, but I'm having trouble finding a Gtk# equivalent to pygtk's DragContext.drag_status. Here's the documentation: http://www.go-mono.org/docs/index.aspx?link=T:Gdk.DragContext/*

Comment: That link is broken--the * is supposed to be part of it.

Comment: Took me a while to find it, too: apparently it's Gdk.Drag.Status in Gtk# (gdk_drag_status in C).

Answer (score 1):

You can define different targets for tags and cards, and on the left widget accept only the target that represents the tags. Use `Gtk.Drag.DestSet` method. Maybe something like:

```
        Gtk.Drag.DestSet (widget, DestDefaults.All,
                      new TargetEntry[1] { new TargetEntry ("MYAPP_TAGS", TargetFlags.App, 1) },
                      DragAction.Default);
```

---

I tried to make the destination emit Motion events with:

```
        Gtk.Drag.DestSet (widget, DestDefaults.Motion,
                      new TargetEntry[1] { new TargetEntry ("MYAPP_TAGS", TargetFlags.App, 1) },
                      DragAction.Default);
```

theoretically, if I understand it correctly, it should work. But I couldn't make it fire motion events :(

Comment: Thanks--I might not have been clear: My problem is not that I don't want the left side to accept both cards and tags (I already use different targets). It's that I only want to be able to drop directly on tags, rather than in between them.